# Beating Iudex Gundyr

Tags: dark-souls-3

At the end of the tutorial area, you reach the first boss of the game in a circular arena.  I'm having some trouble beating this thing.  The first phase is pretty easy as I can roll back from the horizontal slashes or roll sideways against the vertical slashes.

After half the lifebar is gone, it changes forms and has a monumental amount of reach.  In addition to this, I find it very hard to read what the boss is going to do next.  I keep dying when the large arm sweeps out because I keep misjudging the range.

**What do I need to be aware of when fighting this boss so I can evade properly and beat him?**

Comment: Ok, this is purely from my 2 attempts that I went through to beat him. The first time I died because I stayed too far away from him. If you stay close near the actual "center" of him where you see the original legs, most of the large attacks will miss. There is one "butt-pound" style attack he does that you need to watch out for, but other than that, its a pretty safe spot to avoid attacks and finish him. You'll basically want to be under most of his mass for the fight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Aeolingamenfel mentioned, the secret is to get up very close. Once he transforms, he generally attacks by swiping his arm  from the left, biting from the right, or lifting himself up to body slam down. The attacks cover a large area and have a huge range, but if you get right up against his original body (the armor part), the attacks become much more easy to dodge. Just get in close, and be ready to get out as fast as possible once he starts pushing up on his tail.

Comment: Looks like getting in close is a key strategy here.  I'll have to give it a try on my next character.

Comment: @MadMAxJr I went up against him as a deprived class with just a club equipped and once I tried getting up close, he went down pretty fast. Good luck!

Comment: It appears that in his early form, his horizontal attacks will miss if you get in his face and circle-straffe to his left (your right), no dodge required...

Answer (score 1):

Staying away from Iudex Gundyr did the trick for me, if you leave a certain amount of space between the two of you, he will eventually do a jump-attack towards you. When he starts initiating this jump attack, roll forward. You will end up behind him if done properly, just turn around, attack a couple of times and run away again. This also worked for me in his second form. Keep repeating the process untill he is dead.

Managed to kill him this way with the Deprived class and club starting weapon.